# How to maintain same structure from source to target if parent and child xml tags has same name in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

Below is my requirement
I have order input contains Item and each Item contains sub Items but the Tag name is same "Item".

```
<OrderInput>
    <Item>
        <ItemId>
        <ItemName>
        <ItemDesc>
        <Item>
            <ItemId>
            <ItemName>
            <ItemDesc>
            <Item>
                <ItemId>
                <ItemName>
                <ItemDesc>
            </Item>
        </Item>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <ItemId>
        <ItemName>
        <ItemDesc>
        <Item>
            <ItemId>
            <ItemName>
            <ItemDesc>
        </Item>
    </Item>
</OrderInput>
```

After transformation using xslt it should look like below. Parent and chils nodes have same name "Line" like source "Item"

```
<OrderOutput>
    <OrderLine>
    <Line>
        <LineId>
        <LineName>
        <LineDesc>
        <Line>
            <LineId>
            <LineName>
            <LineDesc>
            <Line>
                <LineId>
                <LineName>
                <LineDesc>
            </Line>
        </Line>
    </Line>
    <Line>
        <LineId>
        <LineName>
        <LineDesc>
        <Line>
            <LineId>
            <LineName>
            <LineDesc>
        </Line>
    </Line>
</OrderOutput>
```

Please help me to resolve this.

Comment: Where does that `OrderLine` in the output come from and why is it not closed?

Comment: Sorry..I missed it..please assume </OrderLine>

Answer (score 1):

you can use replace in element name while transforming

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="2.0">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="OrderInput">
        <OrderOutput>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </OrderOutput>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*[starts-with(name(.), 'Item')]">
        <xsl:element name="{replace(name(.), '^Item', 'Line')}">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Hi Rupesh..Thanks for quick reply...My requirement is not replacement of string...for just illustrative purpose I gave the output format.

Comment: @VamsiKrishna for that you can simply convert as element to element mapping, for nested of element if you don't change mapping of document than it would not effect on output. just like first template of above code.